# build.xml in ant

Tags: scripting, ant

Can anybody help me know what these tags do in build.xml file?

```
1)<property file="" location="."/>
2)<property environment=""/>
3)<property name="" value=""/> 
4)<path> id="classpath.base"
5)<pathelement> location="$some.jar"/> 
6)<path> id="classpath.build"> 
7)<path> id="classpath.test">
8)<target></target>
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

In the interest of teaching a man how to fish, here're the docs for the [`<property>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html) tag and the [`<path>` and `<pathelement>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#path) tags.

Answer (score 0):

`<property environment=""/>` is system environment variable
`<property name="" value=""/>` is define variable with value

The `location` attribute specifies a single file or directory relative to the project's base directory (or an absolute filename), while the `path` attribute accepts colon- or semicolon-separated lists of locations. The `path` attribute is intended to be used with predefined paths - in any other case, multiple elements with `location` attributes should be preferred.

`Targets` contain task elements. Each task element of the buildfile can have an id attribute and can later be referred to by the value supplied to this

```
<project name="MyProject" default="dist" basedir=".">
    <description>
        simple example build file
    </description>
  <!-- set global properties for this build -->
  <property name="src" location="src"/>
  <property name="build" location="build"/>
  <property name="dist"  location="dist"/>

  <target name="init">
    <!-- Create the time stamp -->
    <tstamp/>
    <!-- Create the build directory structure used by compile -->
    <mkdir dir="${build}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="compile" depends="init"
        description="compile the source " >
    <!-- Compile the java code from ${src} into ${build} -->
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="dist" depends="compile"
        description="generate the distribution" >
    <!-- Create the distribution directory -->
    <mkdir dir="${dist}/lib"/>

    <!-- Put everything in ${build} into the MyProject-${DSTAMP}.jar file -->
    <jar jarfile="${dist}/lib/MyProject-${DSTAMP}.jar" basedir="${build}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="clean"
        description="clean up" >
    <!-- Delete the ${build} and ${dist} directory trees -->
    <delete dir="${build}"/>
    <delete dir="${dist}"/>
  </target>
</project>
```